# Is there any harm if I don't do const_cast<char*> and simply use ( char * ) typecasting?

Tags: c++, c++11

Just want to know if there is a disadvantage of not using const_cast While passing a char* and simply type-casting it as (char *) or both are basically one and same ?

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include<conio.h>
  using namespace std;

  void print(char * str)
  {
    cout << str << endl;
  }

  int main () 
  {
     const char * c = "sample text";
    //  print( const_cast<char *> (c) ); // This one is advantageous or the below one
     print((char *) (c) );               // Does the above one and this are same? 
    getch();
    return 0;
  }
```

Is there some disadvantage of using `print((char *) (c) );` over   `print( const_cast<char *> (c) );`  or basically both are same ?

Comment: I would say that `const_cast` more accurately describes what the cast does. For example, then one can't incorrectly believe you're casting from an int.

Comment: @Zyx2000: So say that :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko I accidentally pressed the enter key too early.

Comment: In your case you'd better make `print` _const correct_, because if you try make smth non-const with `c` defined like now, you'll get troubles

Comment: @Bo Persson How do i put the grey colour in case I want to highlight the words ?

Comment: @Ritesh - You can read all about comment formatting here http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your `print` function should take a `const char*` parameter instead of just `char*` since it does not modify it. This eliminates the need for either cast.

As for your question, C++ style casts (i.e. `const_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, etc.) are prefered over C-style casts because they express the intent of the cast and they are easy to search for. If I accidentally use an a variable of type `int` instead of `const char*`, using `const_cast` will result in a compile time error. However if I use a C-style cast it will compile successfully but produce some difficult to diagnose memory issues at runtime.

Comment: I did not do anything inside so that i can just place what i wanted to know instead of making things lengthy and uncomfortable for other users to see ;). Thanks for the answr

Answer (score 5):

In this context, they are identical (casting from a "const char*" to a "char*").  The advantages of const_cast are:

1. It will help catch typos (if you accidentally cast a "const wchar_t*" to a "char*", then const_cast will complain.)
2. It's easier to search for.
3. It's easier to see.

Answer (score 4):

The C-style cast `(char *)` is equivalent *if used properly*. If you mess up the `const_cast`, the compiler will warn you, if you mess up the C-style cast you just get a bug.

Answer (score 3):

`const_cast` is more appropriate because it only casts away constness, and otherwise will warn you about other possible mistakes (like converting one pointer type to another etc), and `(char *)` will just silently interpret anything you give it as `char *`. So if you can - better use `const_cast` for better type safety.

Answer (score 1):

Independently on the effect that C cast do in this particular case, C cast and C++ casts are not the same: C++ distinguish between reinterpret, static, dynamic and const cast.

The semantics of these cast are different and not always equally possible.

C cast can be either static or reinterpret cast (where static is not possible). It must be used where such an ambivalence is a requirement (I cannot imagine how and when), it must be avoided where a well defined and expected behavior is needed.